# JSON Url returns something else?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to access this json file : http://www.cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json with Java.

But when I read it, sometimes it gives me a JSON string (that's ok) and sometimes it gives me something else and json.simple.parser throw an `Unexpected character(<) at position 0`.
Based on what I read on stackOverflow, it may be that it returns XML instead of JSON. As my url is "json", how is it possible ?

Here is the code i'm using :

```
String baseUrl = "http://www.cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json";
...
URL url = new URL(this.baseUrl);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String l;
String json = "";
System.out.println(url);
while((l=in.readLine()) != null){
  System.out.println(l);
  json+=l;
}
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
```

and the log is `<`followed by an lot of squares and unknown characters like ÿÕ[s›È and an error `Unexpected character () at position 0.`

Comment: Possibly it does return you json, but incomplete, causing the syntax to be messed up. That, to me, sounds more plausible than something returning JSON one moment and XML the other. Could be wrong though, interesting issue :)

Comment: I suggest you log the result before you try to parse it - that way you can see what's going on rather than guessing. You should also use a `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation like that.

Comment: If I log the result, it gives me something with unknown characters that starts with < and a lot of squares

Comment: @Romain That Log should be part of this question as the output so we can draw to a more accurate resolution.

Comment: I updated the question with the log, I also changed the concatenation for a StringBuilder as you advised @JonSkeet

Comment: I think the json you get isn't in the right format. Java try to read it as Ascii or UTF-8 I think, and get `<ÿÕ[s›È...` instead of `{"key":value, ...` juste because of format reading error.

Comment: What parser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking into account the compression and encoding of the resource returned from the server. The response of a `HEAD` request is the following:

```
rpax@machine:~$ HEAD http://www.cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json
200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 21 Aug 2017 12:02:14 GMT
Age: 112
ETag: "n_s_jQ"
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Encoding: gzip <---- *HERE*
Content-Length: 7902
Content-Type: application/json
Expires: Mon, 21 Aug 2017 12:12:14 GMT
...
```

For avoiding this issue, you can wrap the url stream into a [GZIPInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) :

```
GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(url.openStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis));
// ...
```

And the data returned when executing `readline()` will be decompressed.